# How to create dynamicly scrollController in for loop at flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show some items by category. I can do this with Map but they all depend on a single scrollController. Since there is no fixed number of categories, I cannot do it statically.

How can I create scrollController dynamically in Map.

These two lines give me error.

```
ScrollController  scrollName = 'scrollName'+extra.id.toString();
 ScrollController  scrollName = new ScrollController();
```

My code

```
Column(
            children: order!.extraOrders!.map((extra) {
                            ScrollController  scrollName = 'scrollName'+extra.id.toString();
                            ScrollController  scrollName = new ScrollController();
                            return SingleChildScrollView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              controller: 'dymanicNameWillBe',
                              child: Row(
                                children: extra.items!.map((e) {
                                  return Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          right: 10.0,
                                          bottom: 10,
                                          top: 30,
                                          left: 10),
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, error on these two lines are normal.
Since you are trying to define a **String** to **ScrollController** object, Flutter will throw an error to this line;

```
ScrollController  scrollName = 'scrollName'+extra.id.toString();
A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ScrollController'.
```

On second line, since you have already defined a variable (even if it is not a correct definition) named **scrollName**,
Flutter will throw an error to this line;

```
ScrollController  scrollName = new ScrollController();
The name 'scrollName' is already defined.
```

Also, when you want to define a scroll controller to a **SingleChildScrollView** the object should be a ScrollController, not a String.

---

### **Solution for Dynamic ScrollControllers**

1. Define a global List for **scrollControllers** and initialize it same length as your item list.
2. Pass the **ScrollController** item at index in your **scrollControllers** list as controller to **SingleChildScrollView**

**Example code;**

```
// Global scroll controllers list
List<ScrollController> controllersForExtraOrders = [];

// Arrange global scroll controller list
arrangeExtraOrderScrollControllers() {
   order?.extraOrders?.forEach((extraOrder) {
     ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
     controllersForExtraItems.add(controller);
   });
}

// Build UI with this global scroll controller list
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
   ...

   Column(children: order!.extraOrders!.map((extra) {
        
        // Get the extra order index.
        int extraOrderIndex = order!.extraOrders!.indexOf(extra);
        return SingleChildScrollView(
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           // Pass the controller at extraOrderIndex
           controller: controllersForExtraItems[extraOrderIndex],
           child: ....
        );
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**Bonus**;
If you want to slide to next item, get the scroll controller for that dynamic list and do your stuff.

```
slideToNextItem(int extraOrderIndex) {
    SlideController slideController = controllersForExtraItems[extraOrderIndex];
    slideControllerExtra.animateTo(
       slideControllerExtra.position.pixels + 190,
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
       curve: Curves.ease,
    );
}
```

---

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this flutter package. I think it would solve your problem: https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list